# Community edition, home screen show category list

Tags: category-tree, home, column

Can anybody tell me if its possible to view my all my categories in the left column on the home page?

Being searching and trying things for a while, but still have not being able to get it working.

Tried this code, but its not showing anything. (added it in the editor)

```
 {{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list"
 alias="products_homepage" category_id="2"
 template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the block to System->Permissions->Blocks ? If not, you must add and enable 'catalog/product_list'!

Answer (score 0):

I found out a tutorial in Inchoo

You can take it as a reference

**http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-category-menu-navigation-in-magento/**

I hope it is useful for you